# Numpy Pandas Remove Outliers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a function that will parse through an array of values and then update the array without the values that are determined to be outliers by falling outside of the interquartile range. While I feel like the conditions I have in place will test and output the correct answer, I'm not sure how I should pass a column worth of values into the data frame in a way that will remove the rows that match outlier cases. Currently my data comes back with a typeError.

**Error:** `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str`

**Function:**

```
def reject_outliers_iqr(data):
    q1, q3 = np.percentile(data, [25, 75])
    iqr = q3 - q1

    lower_bound = q1 - (iqr * 1.5)
    upper_bound = q3 + (iqr * 1.5)
    return np.where((data > upper_bound) > (data < lower_bound))
```

**Dataframe:**

```
rawData = pd.read_csv(parent_folder + "/" + csv_file)
print(rawData.head())

     date day_of_week  leads  clicks  sal
0  1/1/17      Sunday      0     527    0
1  1/2/17      Monday      0    1013    0
2  1/3/17     Tuesday      0    1428    0
3  1/4/17   Wednesday      0    1461    0
4  1/5/17    Thursday      0    1429    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function's last line seems to me to contain at least three errors, and should probably be

```
return np.where((data > lower_bound) & (data < upper_bound))
```

1. Data should be *higher* than the lower bound, and *lower* than the upper bound.
2. The logical conjunction is `&`, not `>`.

Once corrected, it ran by me fine, as in (using your data):

```
>>> df.iloc[reject_outliers_iqr(df.clicks)]
    date    day_of_week leads   clicks  sal
0   1/1/17  Sunday  0   527 0
1   1/2/17  Monday  0   1013    0
2   1/3/17  Tuesday 0   1428    0
3   1/4/17  Wednesday   0   1461    0
4   1/5/17  Thursday    0   1429
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you for the answer. Should I set `rawData = reject_outliers_iqr(rawData['clicks'])` to ensure that `rawData` is no based off of a non-outlier set? Or is this not needed because it is already updated after the function is run?

Comment: Maybe using .iloc rather than ix

Comment: @cphill Not sure `rawData` would be a fitting name, then. Perhaps `cleansedData = rawData.ix[reject_outliers_iqr(rawData['clicks'])]`. Also, note that your function returns a `numpy.array`, not a DataFrame.

Comment: @AmiTavory sorry to cause confusion. I guess the original question outside of my method errors was to try and return a DataFrame with rows that are not outliers. Not to return an array. Are you able to help with that task?

Comment: @cphill No problem, but I tried to answer how to do that in the comment (and Wen usefully improved it): if you call `rawData.iloc` on the return value of the function, that should do it.

Comment: @AmiTavory sorry I missed that. Thank you!